# Migrating my application from IIS 6 to IIS 7 doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, iis-6

I'm migrating my website from IIS running on windwos server 2003 to Win server 2008 (64 bit). In both cases, the application is running on .NET 4.0, however, for unknown reason i get the error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" for no obvious reason.

As you can see, everything works well on http://www.matchmypet.com, but when you try to do http://beta.matchmypet.com/home.aspx (which points to the new sever), everything break loose. does anyone have any idea how can i figure out what the issue is? keep in mind that these are exactly the same binaries (compiled against .net 4.0 32 bit, but i would assume that should not make a difference).

Let me know if you have any idea. much appreciated.

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to tell without seeing the code, specifically the line throwing the `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring your Application Pool to use Classic pipeline mode (as opposed to Integrated pipeline).

Also the error page shows that the exception originated from your custom code - deploy a Debug build to see what source code line causes it or at least post the whole method that raises the exception.